# How to use the attribute rendered in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

I want to know how to use the attribute rendered in PrimeFaces.

Does this piece of code make any sense:

```
rendered="#{bean.user 1} and #{bean.user 2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rendered` attribute only accepts boolean values. It defines if a component will be created in your page DOM. If you set a component as `rendered="false"`, it will not be visible in your website.

And answering your question: that piece of code only makes sense if `user1` and `user2` are boolean variables in your bean. Also, don't forget the getters and setters for those variables.

Answer (score 0):

`Rendered` attribute can only accepts `Boolean` value, or if you use `EL` expression, it's expression must evaluate to Boolean value like

```
#{mBean.isTrue} , #{mBean.valueOne eq 1} , #{mBean.valueOne == 1} , #{mBean.stringValue == 'String'} , etc.
```

Hope it's help.